# Adding custom text label in Stacked Bar chart of amCharts

Tags: r, amcharts

I was trying to adjust the Text-label of my Stacked Horizontal Bar chart using *R implementation of amCharts*. Below is my code :

```
 library(RAmCharts)
Dat = data.frame('Type' = c('a', 'b'), 'Value1' = c(97.68648, 97.68648), 'Value2' = c(2.31351, 2.31351), 'z' = NA)
    Fn = htmlwidgets::JS(
                'function(value) {',
                'return value+\'%\';',    
                '}')    

    P = amSerialChart(theme = 'light', categoryField = "Type", precision = 2, rotate = TRUE, hideCredits = TRUE, addClassNames = TRUE, plotAreaBorderAlpha = 1, plotAreaBorderColor = '#000') %>%
                      setDataProvider(dataProvider = Dat, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
                      addGraph(valueField = c("Value1"), fillAlphas = 0.8, bullet = "round", lineThickness = 0, type = 'column', fixedColumnWidth = 50) %>%
                      addGraph(valueField = c("Value2"), fillAlphas = 0.8, bullet = "round", lineThickness = 0, type = 'column', fixedColumnWidth = 50) %>%
                      setBalloon(cornerRadius = 12, textAlign = "left", maxWidth = 1300)

    P@valueAxes = list(list(stackType = 'regular', minimum = 0, maximum = 100)) 
    P
```

I want to have the Text label to be displayed as in https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-bar-chart/, however concatenated with '%' (as with my custom defined function `Fn` here).

I hoped there could be a function like `labelTextFunction` where I could implement above plan, but no success.

Can anyone please guide me how to achieve the same with R implementation of amCharts.

Thanks,

Comment: Try. `P@graphs[[1]]$labelText <- "[[value]]%"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment, here is a way to do so for all graph elements:

```
P@graphs <- lapply(P@graphs, FUN = function(x) {
  c(x, "labelText" = "[[value]]%")
})
```

[image]